strange definition of centrally symmetric - the example given has got to be wrong?
There are so many different definitions of this term 'centrally symmetric' and here is one from book Orthogonal Polynomials of Several Variables 2nd edition pp119-20 that is especially incoherent and ambiguous like many other passages in this book which I paste here.

And/or can we all agree that he is again wrong and another error when he says 'Nevertheless,this function is centrally symmetric.' I see nowhere where $\alpha$ has been defined. As for example i let $\alpha=1,d+1=3$ and use the simple.
|y1-y2||y1-y3||y2-y3| in which case there is no way it can be centrally symmetric. Simply let y1=1,y2=2,y3=3 which does NOT obey either one of the conditions. So do we all agree the author is wrong !

As far as I can see, your example shows that this function is not S-symmetric (agreeing  with the author). But it is clearly centrally symmetric.  The title of your question also suggests a confusion between the 2 kinds of symmetry. The quoted passage defines S-symmetry. The definition of central symmetry was undoubtedly given earlier in the book.

Please do not rely on pictures of text.

@Shaun What is that supposed t mean? That is part of the book!

It means: type it up. Pictures are not user-friendly.

yea that would be clearer but takes a really long time. At one point it did look clearer but i don't know why the system here did not keep it that way. It is not actually a picture even though that is what the icon said , because it was actually capture of window using ifran.I have the book as .pdf file. If there was another way such as is written where begins B I, hyperlink , blockquote , preformatted text , insert citation ' etc. i would try that. The system has the ability to show it much clearer because it did/does at one point of the process. Why it could not keep it that way don't know.

ok u can delete the question and answers if u know how because it would not do it for me

The final and correct verdict. His final function is centrally symmetric but only if use the norm or function which i stated as meaning like a single axis component corresponding to j as in yj or i as in yi and the distance between them which is $(\sqrt{yi^2+yj^2})^\alpha$ and is the same regardless of the signs of the yi.This is not normally what one means when put something between absolute value signs, |...|. When one does that it would usually mean absolute value of (yi-yj) and not what i wrote. He should have written each part as $(\sqrt{yi^2+yj^2})^\alpha$ exactly as i wrote and take the product(s) of such.

Perhaps I'm naïve but I don't see anything wrong with what the author says. I'm assuming alpha is implicitly assumed to be a positive real number.
In your example, replacing $y_3$ by $-y_3$ yields $|y_1-y_2||y_1+y_3||y_2+y_3|$ which is not equal to $|y_1-y_2||y_1-y_3||y_2-y_3|$ in general, whereas replacing each of the $y_i$ by $-y_i$ yields $|y_2-y_1||y_3-y_1||y_3-y_2|$ which is equal to the original expression.

The requirement is that it must pass the 2nd  condition $H(y',y_{d+1})=H(-y',y_{d+1})$ replacing each of yi by -yi for i<3 then it is not equal.
Because |y1-y2||y1-y3||y2-y3| goes to |y1-y2||y1+y3||y2+y3|  unless u mean to take |yi+yj| as equal $\sqrt(yi^2+yj^2)$ such as a euclidean norm but only in those or special class of relations

yea u would assume $\alpha$ can be a positive real number also

I think you're confusing the terms "centrally symmetric" and "S-symmetric". On another note, I've never seen anyone write $|y_i+y_j|$ for $\sqrt(y_i^2+y_j^2)$ - it reeks of "freshman's dream" !

i am not confusing anything. It is written directly from the book paste and right there he defines centrally symmetric, after he defined S symmetric. And if what u say u never seen then that means that the author is wrong it is NOT centrally symmetric because it does NOT pass the 2nd test.Changing the first two yi's to minus the same yi's and leaving the third the same is NOT equal to the original |y1-y2||y1-y3||y2-y3| unless i use the euclidean norm ...$\sqrt{yi^2+yj^2}$. Can you read the part he writes "nevertheless it is centrally symmetric". So it is not by his definition

He says "centrally symmetric with respect to the variables $y'$", then goes on to write that this means that $H(y',y_{d+1})=H(-y',y_{d+1})$. A reasonable reader would infer that a function that is "centrally symmetric" (without adding "with respect to...") would be a function such that $H(-y)=H(y)$ (here $y$ is a vector). Thus his final example is centrally symmetric.

it may be centrally symmetric but only if i took it to mean |yi-yj|=|yi^2+yj^2| or sqrt of such as in Euclidean distance.In which case it is also equal|yi+yj| Otherwise it is not
